# Compatible crankset for my singlespeed

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

i am planning to replace my current crankset and BB with this:

http://www.jensonusa.com/Cranksets/Race-Face-Ride-1X-Crankset?cs=Blue

Would like to know if this compatible with my bike. Currently here's what i know about the specs:

1. Its a single speed with 32t front sprocket and 14t rear cog
2. It has an eccentric bottom bracket, i measured the shell to be 7.3 cm
3. The current crankset i have now is a Truvativ e400 with powerspline bottom bracket

[Here's a photo of my BB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pxVx.jpg), hope it helps.

Comment: Your link points to "OOPS...
SORRY BUT THE PAGE YOU'RE LOOKING FOR CANNOT BE FOUND"

Comment: That's Jenson USA for you. Here's a [google cache link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:glr2lTHPycwJ:www.jensonusa.com/Race-Face-Ride-1X-Crankset+&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru&lr=lang_en%7Clang_ru&forcesession=1).

Comment: @Exordium, can you provide a photo of your bike BB?

Comment: There are a few more issues (mainly chainline) that have to be addressed in addition to whether the BB fits in your frame. What is the bike? Is it a SS MTB? Do you have adjustable dropouts?

Comment: Yes it is an SS MTB, no adjustable dropouts. This is the bike https://www.statebicycle.com/products/pulsar-29er-mountain-bike

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking you'd lose the eccentric BB but realized the english BB threads are *inside* the silver metal excentrics in your photo

Comment: According to Sheldon Brown, SS MTBs have either a 52 or 47.5mm chainline, you will need to measure what you bike runs. I tried to find the chainline specs of the 1x crankset but had no luck. You could contact RF's support to get the crank's specs.